# How to optimize AngularJS config function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I have following config functions and run functions in my app.js file. What is the best way to optimize these function method ? can we move these into one single config function ?
Or Can we move these into another file and use if yes please update my code in comment.

```
.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = true;

    }])
    .run(function($state, $rootScope, $window) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess",
            function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
                $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            });
    })
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
        return $httpProvider.interceptors.push("AuthInterceptor");
    })
    .config(['toastyConfigProvider', function(toastyConfigProvider) {
        toastyConfigProvider.setConfig({
            limit: 2,
            sound: true,
            position: 'top-center',
            shake: false,
            theme: 'material'
        });
    }])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, helloProvider, toastrConfig) {
        helloProvider.init({
            facebook: '1234567899',
            google: '12345890-wgewrgwrgwrgrgwr.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            twitter: 'wgwerwrgwrgwrgwrgwrw'
        }, {
            redirect_uri: 'redirect.html',
            oauth_proxy: 'https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy',
            oauth_version: '1.0a' // probably 1.0a with hello.js

        });
```

Comment: Define "optimize". Have you measured that those functions were too slow to execute, and caused a performance problem? If not, why do you think you should optimize them?

Comment: No there is no performance issue. Is it a good practice to keep multiple config functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could simplify your config functions using a single .config call, then you could also naming your dependencies to handle an uglify process.

```
.config(["cfpLoadingBarProvider", 
         "$httpProvider", 
         "toastyConfigProvider", 
         "$stateProvider", 
         "$urlRouterProvider", 
         "$locationProvider", 
         "helloProvider", 
         "toastrConfig",
    function (cfpLoadingBarProvider, 
              $httpProvider, 
              toastyConfigProvider, 
              $stateProvider, 
              $urlRouterProvider, 
              helloProvider, 
              toastrConfig) {
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = true;
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("AuthInterceptor");
        toastyConfigProvider.setConfig({
            limit: 2,
            sound: true,
            position: 'top-center',
            shake: false,
            theme: 'material'
        });
        helloProvider.init({
            facebook: '1234567899',
            google: '12345890-wgewrgwrgwrgrgwr.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            twitter: 'wgwerwrgwrgwrgwrgwrw'
        }, {
                redirect_uri: 'redirect.html',
                oauth_proxy: 'https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy',
                oauth_version: '1.0a' // probably 1.0a with hello.js

            });
    }])
    .run(function ($state, $rootScope, $window) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess",
            function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
                $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            });
    });
```

If you want to organize your config functions in multiple files, probably the best option is using a bundle, in that case, there are some viable options.
For example, you can use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to concat(minify,uglify) your files, so:

---

**Files**

*File1:*

```
angular.module('mymodule', [])
    .config(["dependencyA", function (dependencyA) {
        dependencyA.doSomething();
    }]);
```

*File1:*

```
angular.module('mymodule', [])
    .config(["dependencyB", function (dependencyB) {
        dependencyB.doSomething();
    }]);
```

*File3:*

```
angular.module('mymodule', ["dependecies..."])
    .run(["authService", (authService) => {
        authService.fillAuthData();
    }]);
```

---

gulp.file

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

gulp.task("ts", () => {
    return gulp.src("./src/js/**/*.js")
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat("dist.js"))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./js/"))
})
```

Same for [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or if your are using [ASP.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).
I prefer starting by a single app/module definition, then I switch on a bundling solution if the solution starting grows.

All the best.

Comment: Can we move this config into sperate files ? What is the best practice ?